# ffmpeg image to video sequence stops after 10

Tags: video, ffmpeg, image, image-conversion

Probably a fast anwser, but my first time trying to do this. I have 77 jpeg pictures, I have renamed them to be 000.jpg - 076.jpg. The next step is using ffmpeg and here is my command statement:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r .1 -i %d.jpg -r 25 test.avi
```

It creates an avi with 10 images for 10seconds each, why only 10? I've tried other iterations of %d.jpg in the ffmpeg command with no success.

thanks for the help all!

-Jim

Here is the listing of the directory with the images:

```
ls -l
total 77472
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim 2329065 May 17 16:31 000.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  716563 May 17 16:31 001.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  716626 May 17 16:31 002.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  726686 May 17 16:31 003.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  739312 May 17 16:31 004.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  720249 May 17 16:31 005.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  666757 May 17 16:31 006.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  656259 May 17 16:31 007.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  664960 May 17 16:31 008.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  740801 May 17 16:31 009.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  882502 May 17 16:31 010.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  631117 May 17 16:31 011.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  730331 May 17 16:31 018.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  725132 May 17 16:31 019.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  729626 May 17 16:31 020.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  731980 May 17 16:31 021.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  671597 May 17 16:31 022.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  681978 May 17 16:31 023.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  686600 May 17 16:31 024.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  675316 May 17 16:31 025.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  681826 May 17 16:31 026.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  740998 May 17 16:31 027.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  568480 May 17 16:31 028.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  747400 May 17 16:31 029.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  630995 May 17 16:31 030.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  689926 May 17 16:31 031.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  685054 May 17 16:31 032.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  710620 May 17 16:31 033.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  658365 May 17 16:31 034.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  657037 May 17 16:31 035.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  772135 May 17 16:31 036.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  741759 May 17 16:31 037.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  807470 May 17 16:31 038.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  748423 May 17 16:31 039.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  712377 May 17 16:31 040.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  715804 May 17 16:31 041.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  701025 May 17 16:31 042.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  759446 May 17 16:31 043.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  621801 May 17 16:31 044.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  720843 May 17 16:31 045.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  704002 May 17 16:31 046.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  696075 May 17 16:31 047.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  723685 May 17 16:31 048.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  732332 May 17 16:31 049.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  747235 May 17 16:31 050.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  883655 May 17 16:31 051.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim 1750723 May 17 16:31 052.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim 1002588 May 17 16:31 053.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  540666 May 17 16:31 054.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim 1876002 May 17 16:31 055.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim 1893761 May 17 16:31 056.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim 1979442 May 17 16:31 057.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim 1766249 May 17 16:31 058.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim 2085989 May 17 16:31 059.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  883871 May 17 16:31 060.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  755714 May 17 16:31 061.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim  797146 May 17 16:31 062.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim 2431531 May 17 16:31 065.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim 2413333 May 17 16:31 066.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim 2449278 May 17 16:31 067.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim 2458183 May 17 16:31 068.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim 2514419 May 17 16:31 069.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim 2477737 May 17 16:31 070.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim 2471347 May 17 16:31 071.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim 2384936 May 17 16:31 072.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim 2459983 May 17 16:31 073.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim 2501286 May 17 16:31 074.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim 2367710 May 17 16:31 075.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jim jim 2455564 May 17 16:31 076.jpg
```

FFMPEG Command and OUTPUT:

```
ffmpeg -v verbose -f image2 -r .1 -i %03d.jpg -r 25 test.avi
ffmpeg version 0.8.1-4:0.8.1-0ubuntu1, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 22 2012 05:09:06 with gcc 4.6.3
  configuration: --extra-version='4:0.8.1-0ubuntu1' --arch=amd64 --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libfreetype --enable-vaapi --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-shared --disable-static
  avutil      configuration: --extra-version='4:0.8.1ubuntu1+medibuntu1' --arch=amd64 --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-version3 --enable-libfreetype --enable-vaapi --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdirac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-version3 --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-version3 --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-shared --disable-static
  avcodec     configuration: --extra-version='4:0.8.1ubuntu1+medibuntu1' --arch=amd64 --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-version3 --enable-libfreetype --enable-vaapi --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdirac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-version3 --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-version3 --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil    51. 22. 1 / 51. 22. 1
  libavcodec   53. 35. 0 / 53. 35. 0
  libavformat  53. 21. 0 / 53. 21. 0
  libavdevice  53.  2. 0 / 53.  2. 0
  libavfilter   2. 15. 0 /  2. 15. 0
  libswscale    2.  1. 0 /  2.  1. 0
  libpostproc  52.  0. 0 / 52.  0. 0
This program is not developed anymore and is only provided for compatibility. Use avconv instead (see Changelog for the list of incompatible changes).
[image2 @ 0x1bef9c0] max_analyze_duration reached

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 0.10 (1/10) -> 0.50 (1/2)
Input #0, image2, from '%03d.jpg':
  Duration: 00:02:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj440p, 1920x2560, 0.10 fps, 0.50 tbr, 0.10 tbn, 0.10 tbc
File 'test.avi' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Incompatible pixel format 'yuvj440p' for codec 'mpeg4', auto-selecting format 'yuv420p'
[buffer @ 0x1bf0100] w:1920 h:2560 pixfmt:yuvj440p
[avsink @ 0x1bf13c0] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted scaler 0' between the filter 'src' and the filter 'out'
[scale @ 0x1bf1ae0] w:1920 h:2560 fmt:yuvj440p -> w:1920 h:2560 fmt:yuv420p flags:0x4
Output #0, avi, to 'test.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf53.21.0
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 1920x2560, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
[buffer @ 0x1bf0100] Changing frame properties on the fly is not supported.
    Last message repeated 10 times
frame=    1 fps=  0 q=5.7 Lsize=      97kB time=0.04 bitrate=19823.2kbits/s    
video:91kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 6.106282%
```

Now test.avi is only 99Kbs and doesn't play anything.

Comment: Closers: CLI is an API.  Since when is asking *"how do I use this complex API"* off topic?

Answer (score 4):

In this case, it should be %03d, since you have three digits.  I'm not sure how it's running otherwise, but I don't think that's causing the problem.  The only thing I can think of is that in your image sequence, image #11 is out of order (named incorrectly).  If images aren't all in sequence, ffmpeg assumes the sequence is done when it can't find the next number.  Either go through and check, or run a variation of the script in the ffmpeg documentation in a console (MinGW if you're on Windows) to automatically rename them.

[Image to Video Encoding](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-single-pictures-into-movies_003f)

If this still doesn't solve it, please post the entire ffmpeg console output (pass "-report" in the ffmpeg command, it saves a text file with the log).

Comment: According to the new directory listing you posted, your images are not in order.  It jumps from 11 to 18.  Which makes sense that your video duration is reported as two minutes, since it can only get through 12 images before the stream ends.